# How do I find all security groups that trust a list of EIPs across multiple AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, automation, devops

I'm using PowerShell with AWS SDK along with cross account IAM roles. Does anyone know if there is an API available to get this?

Comment: What you do you mean by "trust a list of EIPs"? There is no concept of _trust_ in security groups. Do you mean any Security Group that has a rule that _references_ an Elastic IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All API calls are **account-specific**. There, such a script would need to loop through each account and query separately. The script would either need an IAM User credentials for each account, or it could call `AssumeRole()` if it has permission to access and IAM Role in each account.

Within an account, the script would need to retrieve via `DescribeSecurityGroups()`, look through the Inbound rules and find any instances of the Elastic IP addresses.